# Using apply function to calculate the mean of a column

Tags: r, function, dataframe, matrix, apply

After splitting a data frame into multiple data frames by country,I wanted to be able to calculate the mean of the column centralization in each country's data frame that i split. I used tapply which worked and I tried to use sapply() but the weird thing is that all mean values of the country follows the mean value of the first country. I cannot figure out why and I am asked to use sapply as an exercise so I would like to know how i can improve on my code. Any pointer would be appreciated. (it might be a dumb mistake)

INPUT/my code:

```
strikes.df = read.csv("http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~pfreeman/strikes.csv")
strikes.by.country=split(strikes.df,strikes.df$country)
my.fun=function(x=strikes.by.country){
  l=length(strikes.by.country)
  for (i in 1:l){
    return(strikes.by.country[[i]]$centralization %>% mean)
  }
}

sapply(strikes.by.country, my.fun)

#using tapply()
tapply(strikes.df[,"centralization",],INDEX=strikes.df[,"country",],FUN=mean)
```

OUTPUT

```
   0.374644    0.374644    0.374644    0.374644    0.374644 
    Finland      France     Germany     Ireland       Italy 
   0.374644    0.374644    0.374644    0.374644    0.374644 
      Japan Netherlands New.Zealand      Norway      Sweden 
   0.374644    0.374644    0.374644    0.374644    0.374644 
Switzerland          UK         USA 
   0.374644    0.374644    0.374644

 
  Australia     Austria     Belgium      Canada     Denmark 
0.374644022 0.997670495 0.749485177 0.002244134 0.499958552 
    Finland      France     Germany     Ireland       Italy 
0.750374065 0.002729909 0.249968231 0.499711882 0.250699502 
      Japan Netherlands New.Zealand      Norway      Sweden 
0.124675342 0.749602699 0.375940378 0.875341821 0.875253817 
Switzerland          UK         USA 
0.499990005 0.375946785 0.002390639
```

i am given instruction to use sapply after using split; thats why the only thing that occured to me is using for loops.

Comment: Can you maybe provide a bit of your data in the question using `dput()`?
Also you define variable `x` in the function but you do not use it in the function body, you keep using the name of the split data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `sapply` on the `unique` country names. Actually there's no need to split anything.

```
sapply(unique(strikes.df$country), function(x) 
  mean(strikes.df[strikes.df$country == x, "centralization"]))
#   Australia     Austria     Belgium      Canada     Denmark     Finland      France 
# 0.374644022 0.997670495 0.749485177 0.002244134 0.499958552 0.750374065 0.002729909 
#     Germany     Ireland       Italy       Japan Netherlands New.Zealand      Norway 
# 0.249968231 0.499711882 0.250699502 0.124675342 0.749602699 0.375940378 0.875341821 
#      Sweden Switzerland          UK         USA 
# 0.875253817 0.499990005 0.375946785 0.002390639
```

But if you depend on using `split` as well, you may do:

```
sapply(split(strikes.df$centralization, strikes.df$country), mean)
#   Australia     Austria     Belgium      Canada     Denmark     Finland      France 
# 0.374644022 0.997670495 0.749485177 0.002244134 0.499958552 0.750374065 0.002729909 
#     Germany     Ireland       Italy       Japan Netherlands New.Zealand      Norway 
# 0.249968231 0.499711882 0.250699502 0.124675342 0.749602699 0.375940378 0.875341821 
#      Sweden Switzerland          UK         USA 
# 0.875253817 0.499990005 0.375946785 0.002390639
```

Or write it in two lines:

```
s <- split(strikes.df$centralization, strikes.df$country)
sapply(s, mean)
```

### Edit

If `split`ting the whole data frame is required, do

```
s <- split(strikes.df, strikes.df$country)
sapply(s, function(x) mean(x[, "centralization"]))
```

or

```
foo <- function(x) mean(x[, "centralization"])
sapply(s, foo)
```

Comment: thank you but i am given instruction to use sapply after using split; thats why the only thing that occured to me is using for loops, so can you give me some pointers on my code please?

Comment: @Isabella My `split` line is evaluated from inside out, so first `split` is applied, the `sapply(., mean)` is second. See edit!

Comment: thank you :) that is really easy to understand; would it be possible to use split (strikes.df, strikes.df$country) then use sapply with a customized function like i did? (the instructions still specify that i only split by country for the whole data frame)

Comment: thanks, it worked! so is there any way for the for loop to work?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `gapminder::gapminder` dataset as example data this can be achieved like so:

The example code computes mean life expectancy (`lifeExp`) by `continent`.

```r
# sapply: simplifies. returns a vector
sapply(split(gapminder::gapminder, gapminder::gapminder$continent), function(x) mean(x$lifeExp, na.rm = TRUE))
#>   Africa Americas     Asia   Europe  Oceania 
#> 48.86533 64.65874 60.06490 71.90369 74.32621
# lapply: returns a list
lapply(split(gapminder::gapminder, gapminder::gapminder$continent), function(x) mean(x$lifeExp, na.rm = TRUE))
#> $Africa
#> [1] 48.86533
#> 
#> $Americas
#> [1] 64.65874
#> 
#> $Asia
#> [1] 60.0649
#> 
#> $Europe
#> [1] 71.90369
#> 
#> $Oceania
#> [1] 74.32621
```